# NavigationBar setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(_:for:) method not working for title images on iOS 11 Beta

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, swift4, xcode9

The code that works fine on iOS10 (Swift 3) not working on iOS11 Beta (Swift 4 / XCode 9.0 beta)

Setting the image as navigation bar title and adjusting its vertical position:

`self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "some_image"))`
`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(-4.0, for: .default)`

The image does not get adjusted vertically on iOS 11 beta, on iOS 10 it works fine.

Please note that if navigationbar title is set as text (`self.title = "Some title"`) then method `setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(_:for:)` works fine. This issue is only evident when trying to use UIImageView as navigationbar title.

Has anyone experienced something similar lately?

Comment: Submitted bug to Apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an iOS 11 beta SDK bug.

I can confirm that the issue has been resolved in the latest iOS 11 beta 4 (15A5327g) release.